# color of pagination bootstrap current page angular

Tags: angular, pagination, angular8

I want to change color of pagination When in the current page and when you in the first page or last page pagination will disable

disable like this:

[image]

app.html

```
<ul *ngIf="(ticket$| async)?.length != 0" class="pagination justify-content-end">
  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" (click)="previousIndex()">Previous<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a>
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let i of getArrayFromNumber((ticket$| async)?.length); let in = index" class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" (click)="updateIndex(in)">{{in+1}}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" (click)="nextIndex()">Next</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

app.ts

```
  getArrayFromNumber(length) {
    this.max = (Math.ceil(length / 7))
    return new Array(Math.ceil(this.max));
  }

  updateIndex(pageIndex) {
    this.startIndex = pageIndex * 7;
    this.endIndex = this.startIndex + 7;
  }

  previousIndex() {
    if (this.tabindex > 0) {
      this.tabindex -= 1
    }
    this.startIndex = this.tabindex * 7;
    this.endIndex = this.startIndex + 7;
  }

  nextIndex() {
    if (this.tabindex < this.max - 1) {
      this.tabindex += 1
    }
    this.startIndex = this.tabindex * 7;
    this.endIndex = this.startIndex + 7;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below CSS in your css file. Here for example I have used orange background color for current active page , you can change to any color as per your requirements.

```
.pagination > .active > a , .pagination > .active > a:hover, .pagination > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: orange;
    border-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: write in my CSS follow you? but I can change color as per my requirements.

Comment: Yes you can change the color as per your requirements by changing the background color and border color. Here CSS file means component level CSS file.

Comment: I did it but isn't as desired

Comment: if you using bootstrap pagination then it should change the background color of your pagintaion. probably you already have override css somewhere in your code . if possible please share your CSS file code.

Comment: I did it but it's color change all of pagination not current page.